# Is there any way to apply two recyclerview layouts when using ConcatAdapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-concatadapter

[image]

[image]

**(RedBox is MainItem, Blue Box is SubItem)**

I want to list another `RecyclerView item(Sub Item)` inside a `RecyclerView item(Main Item)` as shown in the picture.

In fact, this has already been implemented. I implemented it by using `SubAdapter` in `onBindViewHolder` of `Main Adapter`.

However, since it is an Adapter in an Adapter, I decided that it was complicated.
I found out about `ConcatAdapter` and tried to use it.

However, at least as far as I know, it seems that only one `RecyclerView Layout` can be expressed when using `ConcatAdapter`.

Is there a way to apply each of the `two RecyclerView Layouts` when using `ConcatAdapter`?

Comment: Are you implementing a recyclerview into another ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't understand exactly what you mean.

Comment: Are you trying to make one recylerview inside of another recyclerview ? Or both are separate and you want them one beside another ?

Comment: In terms of UI, I'm trying to implement one Recyclerview insedie of another RecyclerView. As the 'OP' also mentioned, I already implemented this. Put another adapter in one adapter. But I think this method is too complicated, so I'm looking for another way

Comment: `ConcatAdapter` is for **one** `RecyclerView` and possible multiple adapters for **one** `RecyclerView`, so you can achieve by **one** `RecyclerView`. What is difference position `Blue Box` below `Red Box` and `Blue Box` inner below `Red Box`?

Comment: @liveAnyway 
thanks. The `red box` represents the `items` in the `Main Recyclerview`, and the `blue box` represents the `items` in the `nested recyclerview` inside it. The `second image` shows the implementation of the `first image`.